# Как правильно отображать toolbar?

Tags: java, android

Как правильно отображать toolbar?
Приложение отображается поверх верхней строки уведомлений, как пофиксить?

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_activity_DrawerLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
        layout="@layout/tool_bar"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" />

    <su.gamepoint.opendomofon.pro.sliding.SlidingTabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:elevation="2dp"
        android:background="@color/ColorPrimary"/>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        ></android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

</LinearLayout>


</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Покажите разметку и стили

Comment: http://rgho.st/6SLGlFmZ7 - activity_main.xml

Comment: http://rgho.st/6TnrTXqM8 - styles.xml

Comment: Не надо ссылок, доплните вопрос

Comment: И попробуйте обернуть тулбар в AppBarLayout

Comment: Всем огромное спасибо, исправил

Comment: Если вы решили проблему, то опишите в ответе, т.е. в этом посте, как - это может помочь будущим посетителям страницы)

Comment: Пожалуйста, не отвечайте фразой «спасибо». Вместо этого, **[отметьте лучший ответ как принятый](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)** (галка напротив выбранного ответа). - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/105199)

Answer (score 2):

Примените атрибут `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` к корневому элементу `layout`.

**UPD.**
Также можете попробовать добавить:

```
<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
```

в `<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">` в файле `styles.xml`.

Comment: Присутствует,                                          <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_activity_DrawerLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

Comment: @АндрейУжегов, Посмотрите **UPD**.